# JQuery .html() insertion method won't take PHP file_get_contents() as an argument

Tags: php, jquery

Here is the code:

```
echo "<script>jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{ $('.page-id-24 .entry-content').html('" . file_get_contents('about.php') . "'); });</script>";
```

**Note:** *In my about.php file it has: `<?php echo "html content..."; ?>`*

**Results: I get nothing.**

**What's wrong? What am I not understanding?**

Answer (score 0):

Your code reads the entire contents of `about.php` and dumps it into the middle of your string, but it does not attempt to execute any PHP. The result is a string of data starting `<?php`  that the browser attempts to interpret as HTML. It doesn't understand PHP, so the result is unpredictable, and will depend on the exact contents of `about.php`.

Say for example, that your `about.php` contains the following:

```
<?php echo "<div>Some text</div>"; ?>
```

Strip all the PHP to leave just the HTML and change the name to `about.html`:

```
<div>Some text</div>
```

You could just stop here and update your PHP code to read the `about.html` file:

```
echo "<script>jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{ $('.page-id-24 .entry-content').html('" . file_get_contents('about.html') . "'); });</script>";
```

This will work provided your `about.html` doesn't contain any single-quote characters.

There is a much easier way of doing this.

Edit `about.php` to produce `about.html` as above, then change your script to get jQuery to load the file direct from the server:

```
echo "<script>jQuery(document).ready(function($){ $('.page-id-24 .entry-content').load('about.html'); });</script>";
```

Comment: I'm getting a 404. It is fetching in entire url path that does not exist. So, I then redefined the url path into a php variable. The browser console now shows the correct url path I wanted, but still a 404.

Comment: Dd you upload `about.html` to your web server?

Comment: Yes. Well. I'm coding in a Linux Command line environment.